# Nested http request map Rxjs Angular Ionic

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I want to recognize when a session has expired and make a relogin to make a specific backend call. So when I call `readPersons` I want to detect the session expired and make a relogin and then call the `readPersons` again. So the `readPersons` function in PersonPage should get the answer after the second backend call `readPersons` in case of Status Code 303.
But this not works.

Here is my PersonPage…

```js
readPersons() {
    this.backendService.readPersons().subscribe(
        success => this.handleSuccess(success),
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
    );
}
```

Here is the backendService…
My backend returns 303 when session expired.

```js
readPersons() {
    return this.http.get(PERSONS_URL)
      .map(this.handleSuccess)
      .catch(this.handleError);


      private handleSuccess() {
         if (res.status === 303) {
            return _this.loginService.login().map(() =>{
            return _this.http.get(PERSONS_URL);
          }
    }

    return res.json() || {};
  }
```

Comment: what is `_this` referring to?

Answer (score 0):

_this is set in conctructor from this. 
Thé Workflow is not correct.
Here is the call stack...
1. ReadPersons (BackendService)
2. handleSuccess code 303 is returned (BackendService)
3. LoginSeevice login called
4. ReadPersons in PersonPage got response

But I want that ReadPersons form BackendService has to be called in step 4 before PersonPag. got İt's result